# Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") error

Tags: java, jdbc

I have simple class. Then I try to compile and run it I see ClassNotFoundException.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBProcessor{

private static String serverAdres = "127.0.0.1:5432";

private static String DBname = "dota";
private static String clientName = "postgres";
private static String password = "master";
private static Connection connection;

public static void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                + "Include in your library path!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + serverAdres + "/" + DBname, clientName, password);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (connection == null) {
        System.err.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    DBProcessor db = new DBProcessor();
    db.connect();
}
}
```

I'm using Windows cmd:

```
C:\rmi2>javac -classpath postgresql.jar DBProcessor.java
C:\rmi2>java DBProcessor
Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? Include in your library path!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at DBProcessor.connect(DBProcessor.java:12)
at DBProcessor.main(DBProcessor.java:34)
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:
5432/dota
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at DBProcessor.connect(DBProcessor.java:20)
at DBProcessor.main(DBProcessor.java:34)
Failed to make connection!
```

What  I'm doing wrong?
So, this is postgrsql library  https://www.dropbox.com/s/idx5l0kub5rn1b8/postgresql.jar?dl=0

Comment: To paraphrase: Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? Did you include in your library path?

Comment: -classpath postgresql.jar it is library path?

Comment: @otopba Don't know. What is the result of `jar tvvf postgresql.jar`?

Comment: The `-classpath` directive will only help your code compile, not help it run

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it's library from official site.  http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: @kolossus so, what I need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the command line, this

```
java DBProcessor
```

should be

```
java -cp .;postgresql.jar DBProcessor
```

And, because it includes `java.sql.Driver`, when you have it working you could remove

```
// try {
//    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
// } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
//    System.err.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
//            + "Include in your library path!");
//    e.printStackTrace();
// }
```

Per the [`DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) Javadoc,

> The `DriverManager` methods `getConnection` and `getDrivers` have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of `java.sql.Driver`. For example, to load the `my.sql.Driver` class, the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file would contain the entry:
>
> ```
>  my.sql.Driver
> ```
>
> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()` will continue to work without modification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the driver to your IDE.
if you're using Netbeans, right click on Libraries, Add jar/folder then browse to the driver.

Answer (score 0):

If the postgresql.jar file is not accessible to the Java runtime environment you
will get a 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver' exception.

The easiest way to make the postgresql jdbc driver accessible to your
applications is to install it as a Java Extension. The only thing you need to do
is cp, mv or ln the postgresql.jar file into the Java extension directory. There
is no need to set CLASSPATH if you do this.
The Java extension directory is $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext ($JAVA_HOME on my system
is /usr/java/jdk1.3) or for Windows C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext

This makes life REALLY easy; I didn't have to set CLASSPATH at all in my environment again!