# Java: trivial setup, but can't resolve "ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver"

Tags: java, postgresql, jar

On Mac, installed Java 12.0.2, postgresql-42.2.8.jar, PostgreSQL 11.5. From what I can tell, that version of the JDBC driver should be compatible with that version of PostgreSQL.

I've tried putting the PG jar file in my /Java/Extensions directory, and in the same directory as the following test program, and even set CLASSPATH to my test program directory, but I'm still getting ClassNotFound at runtime for the line `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` in my test program:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class PostgreSQLJDBC {
   public static void main(String args[]) {

ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

      Connection c = null;
      try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
            "postgres", "123");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
   }
}
```

The test program is taken directly from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm

Any help/suggestions much appreciated... thanks.

Comment: possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766843/class-fornameorg-postgresql-driver-error

Comment: You are using an old style connection method.   JDBC4 works differently now.    As long as your driver is located on system classloader, by whatever method,  then it should work.     If its not on the system classloader, you can still load it with a jdbc driver shim.

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath probably needs to explicitly reference the postgresql jar file. That's what I've always done. There might be some magic associated with putting jars in a particular directory, but I'm 99% sure that referencing a random directory in the classpath won't traverse .jar files, only .class files.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph! Got me past that... on to the next roadblock... :-)